# Looping through two separate if statements

Tags: java, arrays, loops

The code below is a simplified version of a method I am working on for a java project. The method will sort through a list of items(two different categories), in this case 0,s and 1's. The code reads through an array of numbers stops at either 0 or 1 and then prints out both the 0 or one and the string of numbers following the 0 or 1. If a preceding string is a 1 or a zero then it will stop and switch to another if statement. However it only executes each statement once. However there is more in the array that it needs to read through and organize. I would like to set up some sort of loop so that it loops through the set of if statements until it has read through the entire array.

```
public class tester 
{

    public static void main(String[] args ) 
    {
        String flags[] = {"0","23","25","34","1","9","12","13","0","67","2","43"};
        String array[] = new String[flags.length];
        String zeros [] = new String[array.length];
        String ones[] = new String[array.length];

        int i,j,k,h;
        int count = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<flags.length; i++)
        {

            if (flags[i].equals("0")) 
            {       
                for (j=0; !flags[j].equals("1") ; j++)
                {
                    count = j+1;
                    array[j] = flags[j];
                    zeros[j] = flags[j];
                }   

            } else
                if (flags[count].equals("1"))
                {
                    j = 0;
                    for(k=count; !flags[k].equals("0");k++)
                    {
                        array[k] = flags[k];
                        j++;
                        ones[j-1] = flags[k];
                    }       
                }

        }

        for(i=0; i<zeros.length; i++)
        {System.out.println(zeros[i]);}

        System.out.println();

        for(i=0; i<ones.length; i++)
        {System.out.println(ones[i]);}
    }
}
```

What it prints out now:

```
0
23
25
34
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null

1
9
12
13
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String flags[] = {"9","0","23","25","34","1","9","12","13","0","67","2","43"};
    String array[] = new String[flags.length];
    String zeros [] = new String[array.length];
    String ones[] = new String[array.length];

    int i;

    boolean addingZeroes = false;
    boolean addingOnes = false;
    int zeroCount = 0;
    int onesCount = 0;

    for (i = 0; i<flags.length; i++) {

        if (flags[i].equals("0")) {
            zeros[zeroCount] = flags[i];
            zeroCount++;
            addingZeroes = true;
            addingOnes = false;
        } else if (flags[i].equals("1")) {
            ones[onesCount] = flags[i];
            onesCount++;
            addingZeroes = false;
            addingOnes = true;
        } else if (addingZeroes) {
            zeros[zeroCount] = flags[i];
            zeroCount++;
        } else if (addingOnes) {
            ones[onesCount] = flags[i];
            onesCount++;
        }

    }

    for(i=0; i<zeroCount; i++) {
        System.out.println(zeros[i]);
    }

    System.out.println();

    for(i=0; i<onesCount; i++) {
        System.out.println(ones[i]);
    }
```

Hey, couple things were wrong. Basically, you need a little state machine where you need to know whether you are in the midst of storing the sequence after a 1 or a 0. I used the boolean values (eg addingZeroes) for that. 
Then, you need to separately keep track of your element count (eg zeroCount) for each of the storage arrays. You might have 20 digits after a 0 and just 2 after a 1.
Finally, at the end, your length of your storage arrays is not what you want - you want the amount of values you ended up storing. That's why you got all those "nulls".
One other thing I noticed is that your j value is initialized always to 0 in the 0 block, so you would always be using the lowest values of the start array.

Comment: could you please explain a bit what the problem was?